# Is there an API for adding/updating identity providers in WSO2?

Tags: wso2

We are considering use of WSO2 to allow customers to access a cloud-hosted vendor system via SAML. Our goal is to build a self-service solution where customers can upload their IdP metadata. At that point we can have code that parses the SP metadata and then makes appropriate calls to WSO2 API to add a new identity provider. I have been unable to locate appropriate documentation for how to accomplish this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Found this documentation:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+the+Identity+Provider+API#UsingtheIdentityProviderAPI-addIdp

I will test this and see if it works as expected.